# Secondary server testing environment

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

I want to test our secondary e-mail server but the primary one right now works correctly. How can I manage to make that server slow down a bit by using dns records and test the secondary server ?

Once at a time I did this by not writing the ns servers addresses correctly.

Do you know another approach ?

Thanks
Baris

Answer (score 2):

MX records include a priority field.  The smaller one is tried first.  If they are equal, then they are tried at random.

However, I don't suggest you do it using DNS.  If something goes wrong, it will take too long to fix, and you can affect your mail.

What I usually do is temporarily block incoming TCP port 25 from a specific client (usually one I control) and then test.  This will let you test the mail servers but not affect production.

Comment: +1 for blocking port 25